# How to add and delete the specific item from an array of an object in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, mern

I am trying to add a functionality wherein when a user clicks on `add channel` button he can add the channel and it will show the newly added channel name in the respective teams. Similarly, when a user wants to delete a channel he can delete it so by clicking on `delete` button.

However, I figured out most of the code but seems like when am updating my newchannel list using useState it is showing me the error saying `teams.channels.map` is undefined and can not read properties.

If anyone can help on this would really be helpful and appreciated.

Please find the source code link below

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/practice-code-test-oifzsf?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `InputAddChannel` component

```
const InputAddChannel = ({ handleAddChannel }) => {
  const [inputChannelValue, setInputChannelValue] = useState("");
  const handlInputChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newChannelName = event.target.value;
    setInputChannelValue(newChannelName);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input
        placeholder="add channel"
        value={inputChannelValue}
        onChange={handlInputChange}
      />
      <button
        disabled={!inputChannelValue}
        onClick={() => handleAddChannel(inputChannelValue)}
      >
        Add channel
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

and pass `handleAddChannel` function to it

```
const App = () => {
  const [newchannel, setNewChannel] = useState(teams);
  const [addteam, setAddteam] = useState("");

  const handleAddChannel = (team, i) => {
    const newData = newchannel.map((channel, index) => {
      if (i === index)
        return {
          ...channel,
          channels: [
            ...channel.channels,
            {
              channelName: team,
              channelid:
                channel.channels[channel.channels.length - 1]?.channelid + 1 ||
                1
            }
          ]
        };
      return channel;
    });
    setNewChannel(newData);
  };

  const handleDeleteChannel = (cid, teamid) => {
    const newData = newchannel.map((channel, index) => {
      if (index === teamid)
        return {
          ...channel,
          channels: channel.channels.filter((c, i) => i !== cid)
        };
      return channel;
    });
    setNewChannel(newData);
  };

  const handleAddteam = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const addteaminput = event.target.value;
    setAddteam(addteaminput);
  };

  const handlSubmitAddteam = () => {
    const newaddedteam = newchannel.concat({
      name: addteam,
      channels: [
        {
          channelid: newchannel.length + 1,
          channelName: "new"
        }
      ]
    });
    setNewChannel(newaddedteam);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        {newchannel &&
          newchannel.map((team, i) => (
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                gap: "0.5rem",
                alignContent: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
                border: "1px solid black",
                padding: "0.5rem"
              }}
              key={i}
            >
              <h1> {team.name} </h1>
              <InputAddChannel
                handleAddChannel={(value) => handleAddChannel(value, i)}
              />

              <div>
                {team.channels.map((c, cid) => (
                  <div
                    style={{
                      display: "flex",
                      gap: "1rem",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      border: "1px solid lightgray"
                    }}
                    key={cid}
                  >
                    <h6> {c.channelName}</h6>
                    <button
                      style={{ width: "5rem", height: "2rem" }}
                      onClick={() => handleDeleteChannel(cid, i)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}

        <input
          placeholder="add team"
          value={addteam}
          onChange={handleAddteam}
        />
        <button disabled={!addteam} onClick={handlSubmitAddteam}>
          Add team
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

You can check in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practice-code-test-forked-hxdzwb?file=/src/App.js:86-3095). Hope it help!

Comment: Hi @iamhynq thank you for the reply answer. This is the solution I was looking for. But just to know what did I miss here and what went wrong so that will take care in future. Hope dont mind asking you. Thanks